# Need script or Lambda to Automate single DB restore from S3 bucket to AWS RDS for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I need a script or Lambda to Restore specific DB from S3 bucket to AWS RDS for MYSQL.
I have user SQL Server Agent job to backup MS SQL database but have no clue if we have any job in MYSQL to run stored procedure.

Comment: This is a bit all over the place. You have data in S3 that is an output of an MS SQL backup that you want to use to build a database in mysql on Amazon RDS? What kind of backup did you make from your SQL Server? I'm hoping it's akin to raw data, otherwise trying to get your sql server backup to load a mysql database is going to be rough.

Comment: Can you list-objects with aws cli to show us backup in S3?